# How is attribute com.apple.quarantine represented in AppleDouble files?

Tags: macos, xattr

I'm working on some code that creates/extracts Zip files and I want to propagate the extended attributes the way Apple compress/uncompress utilities do including the attribute apple.com.quarantine. The Apple compress/uncompress utilities store attribute data in "hidden" AppleDouble files under __MACOSX in the Zip file. In an [AppleDouble](https://stackoverflow.com) file, the extended attributes are stored in an extension to the FinderInfo entry following the magic keyword ATTR. The details of the attribute representation are described in Apple's open source [copyfile.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/copyfile/copyfile-138/).

For most attributes, the binary data exactly matches what one would get viewing the attributes from the command line like:

```
xattr -px some.attribute file
```

However... digging through the code of copyfile one finds that it special cases some attributes, specifically:

```
com.apple.quarantine (XATTR_QUARANTINE_NAME)
com.apple.FinderInfo (XATTR_FINDERINFO_NAME)
com.apple.acl.text (XATTR_SECURITY_NAME)
```

For com.apple.quarantine, copyfile calls qtn_file_to_data to construct the binary and this routine doesn't appear in the open source.

For a typical quarantine attribute like:

```
xattr -l file.png                           
com.apple.quarantine: 0082;632a39ad;Preview;

xattr -px com.apple.quarantine file.png
30 30 38 32 3B 36 33 32 61 33 39 61 64 3B 50 72 
65 76 69 65 77 3B
```

In the corresponding AppleDouble file, the actual binary data (152-176) is:

```
0000144                                    71  2f  30  30  38  32  3b  36
0000160    33  32  61  33  39  61  64  3b  50  72  65  76  69  65  77  3b
0000176    00
```

The 30 30 38 32... is just the characters starting with "0082.." but 2 extra bytes (71 2f) have been pushed in front and the 00 appended at the end.

Can anyone shed some light on this representation?

In copyfile.c, the corresponding decoding method is qtn_file_init_with_data. I guess I can just call this like copyfile does but I'd like to better understand what's going on.

Use of quarantine is an important part of Apple security and has figured in previous Mac vulnerabilities such as [CVE-2021-1810](https://labs.withsecure.com/publications/analysis-of-cve-2021-1810-gatekeeper-bypass) so I'm trying prevent my application introducing a potential vulnerability.

Comment: From a deleted non-answer: The format of the com.apple.quarantine attribute is described well in this article. https://0xmachos.com/2019-02-01-Quarantine-Intro/